# Single page Wordpress website - custom fields or meta boxes or something else?

Tags: custom-field

Hoping someone can give me a pointer in the right direction.
I'm building a website for my friend who's getting married and they've asked to be able to update the site themselves - fair enough.

So, what I've done so far is create my main page in Wordpress and assigned that as the template to the 'home' page.

For each of the sections, I've created new pages in the Wordpress CMS and used `<?php show_post('Hen and Stag'); ?>` to display the content in the relevant section of the page.

The part I'm having problems with is the 'wedding section' - each person require a title, a brief intro and a picture - see here http://www.elandsebswedding.co.uk/main-page/

I'm fairly certain that creating multiple pages for each of the wedding party isn't the best way to tackle this situation, so is there a way that I could use featured images / custom fields to display it instead?

And would I assign these to the 'wedding party' page? In which case I guess I would need to tell my main template page where to get the info from?

I hope this makes sense? If there's an easier way of doing this then I'm all ears!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Posts for anything in the site?  If not, you could make each person's information a post, and and give them each a category -- ie, "Bride", "Groom", "Bridesmaids", "Groomsmen".  Each post could have a title, a description (in the Content area), a Featured Image that you could pull, and an optional Excerpt.  You'd be able to sort them by the category they're in, as well.

If you're already using Posts for some other purpose, you could set up [custom post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types) for the wedding party instead.

Comment: Yes! That's how I've ended up doing it :)